# How to improve the accuracy of Azure Speech-to-Text API?

Tags: azure, speech-to-text

in the last few weeks I have been trying to find a good Speech-to-Text API for Brazilian Portuguese. I have tried Google Cloud, Amazon, IBM and Microsoft but none gave me a result as accurate as [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=roxanne.audio.to.tex&hl=en_US). This app supports multiple languages, and even punctuation! I don't believe the developer has trained a model for the 20+ language it offers. While I am not able to know which api this guy is using (I have sent him an email but I haven't received any reply yet), I have begun using Azure CognitveServices Speech Api, which, through my tests, has been the most accurate one. However, I am still not satisfied with the transcriptions I am getting. Is there a way to improve the accuracy? My goal is to transcript different kind of audios: interviews, lectures, etc. It won't be always the same speaker or the same environment. Even if the input files are not the same in nature, is it worth to train my own model?

Any tips are welcome.

I have been using [this code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/258949599ec32c8a7b03fb38a53f2033010b6b26/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py#L185)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way for you to do that, since ML models are trained by Microsoft.

Comment: They have something called [Custom Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-train-model). They might be useful only for very specific data, though. I am not sure if it's worth to train them for such a general use like mine.

Comment: from my understanding, custom models are more related to teach how to say brand names, abbreviations and things like that. For general usage, I don't think it will solve your needs. As a brazillian portuguese speaker,I would love use this too, but there are some interesting challenges such as different accents for same words. (pretty much the same as american / british english)